# how to ping a certain ip in a c++ program

Tags: c++, ping

Usually I just use the `system("ping 8.8.8.8");` command, but I am trying to store information in a variable (IP) and then ping that IP using system in a c++ program.

This seems very easy, but when I tried to execute the code, it tells me there are too many arguments in function call. Can anybody please help me with a solution to this?

```cpp
ImGui::PushItemWidth(100);
static char IP[64] = ""; ImGui::InputText("PING IP", IP, 64);
ImGui::PopItemWidth();

if (ImGui::Button("ping test")) {
    system("ping ", IP);
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the exact error message?

Comment: `system` doesn't take multiple arguments. It takes one. Pass it one argument.

Comment: The `system()` funrtion can only take a single `const char *` parameter, you have to prepare any stuff you wan to execute in that string first. An you probably don't want to use `system()` to do this, since you have no further control over the results, besides the exit status of the executed program.

Comment: Error (active) E0140 too many arguments in function call example_win32_directx9 C:\Users\PC\Desktop\imgui-master\examples\example_win32_directx9\main.cpp 175 

https://imgur.com/a/oQHZNxB

Comment: @wetpp To add additional information, that was requested in comments, [edit] your question please.

Comment: Check out this guide from The Ping Page, http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage.htm. They have a link to full source on the original Unix ping(8). I'll also provide the link on Unix Ping(8) http://www.ping127001.com/pingpage/ping.text. You might get some help here

Answer (score 1):

The `system()` function takes exactly one argument, as defined by its header file:

`int system( const char* command );`

It expects a full command string to be executed by the shell.

The easiest way to handle this case will be to concatenate the `"ping"` string literal and the `IP` variable. You can do it using `std::string` instead of char arrays pretty easily in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    std::string IP ("127.0.0.1");
    std::string CMD ("ping " + IP);
    std::system(CMD.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should at least show how to finally call `system()` using that string. I am pretty sure that's the 1st thig the OP will complain about.